# Query mongoDb with REST interface

Tags: mongodb, rest

This is my collections:

```
{
  "offset" : 0,
  "rows": [ 
    {
      "_id" : { "$oid" : "5199e109f456aab938b304de" }, 
      "type" : "cluster", 
      "id" : "1", 
      "vertices_transformation" : [ [ 1, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 1 ] ], 
      "vertices" : [ [ 1, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 1 ] ], 
      "v_attributes" : [[0.5,0.8,1], [0.6,0.9,1], [0.44,0.8,0.7],[0,1,0]]
    },
    {
      "_id" : { "$oid" : "5199d8f8f456aab938b304db" }, 
      "type" : "model", 
      "id" : "modello1", 
      "name" : "MODELLO 1", 
      "description" : "1 modello di prova", 
      "clusters" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 ], 
      "clusters_tree" : [ 1, 2, 3, [ 4, 5, 6, 7 ], [ 8, 9, 10, 11 ] ] 
    }
  ],
  "total_rows" : 2,
  "query" : { "type" : "cluster", "id" : 1 } ,
  "millis" : 1
}
```

I want to filter by type and after by id, this is my query:

```
http://xxxx/db/collections/?filter_type=cluster&filter_id=1
```

But the result of this query is 0 rows,but if the query is only by type ,the row is succesfully returned.
Why my query does not work with id?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: is the issue resolved. I have same issue. 
I am trying to pass the URL through browser. and cannot pass JSON message body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is a type mismatch:

```
// your record:
"id" : "1" // id is a string

// your query
"id" : 1   // id is a number
```

Apparently, the REST interface does some implicit conversion on query parameters that look like a number. I don't know how you can prevent that from happening, though.

**EDIT:** [httpie](https://github.com/jkbr/httpie) can send the query as JSON, in the message body. That works:

```
$ http get 'http://127.0.0.1:28017/DB/COLLECTION/' 'filter_id=678' 
...
{
  "filter_id": "678" // id is sent as a string
}
...
"total_rows" : 1     // and now it matched a record
```

I don't know what client you're using, but try sending the query as JSON in the body (but do make it a `GET` request, when you use `POST` MongoDB things you're creating a record).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I have solved my problem inserting id as an int.